# the DFT of a periodic signal represented by a fourier series

Tags: dft, fourier-series

If I have a signal represented by a Fourier series(like in the photo), which is sampled with $T_s$:

$$x[n]=x(t=nT_s) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}a[m]e^{j2\pi m(nT_s)/T_0} $$

How do I find its DFT? I can't understand that. 
Sorry for the English mistakes.

Comment: What is the relationship (if any) between the period of the _signal_ (or, if you prefer, the fundamental frequency in the Fourier series representation) and the sampling interval $T_s$?

Comment: i ask about the general solution but you can assume T0/Ts is an integer

Comment: If you are using Matlab/Octave, it's as easy as `dct(x)` where x is the data.

Comment: Then perhaps you could clarify whether you want the DFT of $(x[0], x[1],\ldots, x[N-1])$ or the DTFT of the infinitely long (but periodic) sequence of samples $\ldots, x_{-2T_s}, x_{-T_s}, x_0, x_{T_s}, x_{2T_s},\ldots$

Comment: If Ts is the reciprocal of the data sampling frequency then what is that strange T0 value? Do those a[m] samples represent some sort of frequency-domain samples? Are you really saying each x[n] sample is equal to the sum of an infinite number of complex numbers? Are you sure your equation is correct? By the way, in order to compute the DFT of an x[n] sequence, that sequence must be finite in length.

Comment: @RichardLyons, depends on what exactly you mean by the "DFT".  i generally equate "DFT" with "DFS", but some folks do not.  (they're mistaken, of course.)

Comment: My last sentence is claiming that we can't perform the DFT, or the inverse DFT, on an infinite-length sequence of samples.